# Jumping between open files in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a shortcut for jumping between already open files in vscode? By jumping I mean changing focus and putting my cursor in that file.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to switch between tabs, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to focus on file explorer and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to focus on the editor.